# How do I ask the Vision API to apply multiple features on an image from java

Tags: java, google-cloud-vision

How do I call the Vision API for LABEL_DETECTION and FACE_DETECTION in one request with java API.
In java-docs-samples i didn't find an example for multiple feature on one request

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer !
if some one hade the same quwetion,

```
    Feature featureFACE = new Feature();
    Feature featureLABEL = new Feature();
    featureLABEL.setType("LABEL_DETECTION").setMaxResults(maxResults);
    featureFACE.setType("FACE_DETECTION").setMaxResults(maxResults);

    AnnotateImageRequest request = new AnnotateImageRequest()
            .setImage(new Image().encodeContent(data))
            .setFeatures(ImmutableList.of(featureFACE,featureLABEL));
```